# Unexpected behaviour of v-bind:class and cookies (Vue js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies

I'm trying to code in Vue js a text which changes it's color on a click and saves it's state in a cookie. It works good on the first visit (no cookie), color is changing properly, but after refreshing color always turns green. I thought there's a problem with cookie, so I displayed it's value (true/false) in a different  and it's working properly. Only color doesn't work.

I've used that cookie library -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies

Video with the problem -> https://streamable.com/ky2l1z

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    
    <h1 v-bind:class='{cookieColor: color}'>{{ color }}</h1>
    <h1 v-bind:class='{cookieColor: color}'>COLOR</h1>
    <button @click="setCookie">CHANGE COLOR</button>

</div>


<script>

    //CHECKS IF COOKIE EXISTS
    var cookieCheck = $cookies.get('isDark');  

    if(cookieCheck === 'undefined'){
        cookieCheck = false;
        console.log('COOKIE DOESNT EXIST');
    }else{
        console.log("COOKIE EXISTS")
    }


    new Vue({

        el: '#app',
        data: {
            color: cookieCheck,
        },
        methods: {
            setCookie(){
                this.color = !this.color;
                $cookies.set('isDark', this.color);
                var cookieCheck = $cookies.get('isDark');
                console.log(this.color);
            }
        },
    })
</script>

<style>

    h1{
        color:black;
    }      

    .cookieColor{
        color: rgb(157, 207, 157);
    }

</style>
```

Comment: try `console.log(typeof cookieCheck)` in else block. it seems that the stored value is converted to string, which always evaluate to true

Comment: Thanks, that's it, but how can i convert it to boolean? I' struggling with it since you commented and can't make it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing the string value to Boolean using JSON:

```
var cookieCheck = $cookies.get('isDark');  

if (cookieCheck === 'undefined') {
    cookieCheck = false;
    console.log('COOKIE DOESNT EXIST');
} else {
    console.log("COOKIE EXISTS")
    // if it exists parse the value
    cookieCheck = JSON.parse(cookieCheck)
    // Check its type
    console.log(typeof cookieCheck)
    // >> boolean
}
```